# How to get Outlook appointments via Excel VBA without master appointments that have recurrences?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a function that pulls appointments from Outlook, using a date range generated by the user, which then outputs the results in a `MsgBox`.

I would like to display scheduled appointments without displaying master appointments that have recurrences.

My date is defined in `startDate`. Normally this date is defined from a UserForm using a date picker, I have manually entered a date for the purpose of this question.

I have set `oAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = False` and get the master appointments.

```
Public Function getOutlookAppointments() As String
    Dim oOutlook              As Object
    Dim oNS                   As Object
    Dim oAppointments         As Object
    Dim oFilterAppointments   As Object
    Dim oAppointmentItem      As Object
    Dim bOutlookOpened        As Boolean
    Dim sfilter               As String
    Dim displayText As String
    Dim startDate As Date
    Const olFolderCalendar = 9
 
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Could not get instance of Outlook, so create a new one
        Err.Clear
        Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        bOutlookOpened = False    'Outlook was not already running, we had to start it
    Else
        bOutlookOpened = True    'Outlook was already running
    End If

    DoEvents
 
    Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    
    oAppointments.Sort "[Start]"
    oAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = False
    startDate = "07/16/2019"
 
    sfilter = ("[Start] < """ & Format(startDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """ and [Start] > """ & Format(startDate + 1, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """")
    Set oFilterAppointments = oAppointments.Items.Restrict(sfilter)
    Debug.Print oFilterAppointments.Count & " appointments found."
    'Iterate through each appt in our calendar
    
    For Each oAppointmentItem In oFilterAppointments
        getOutlookAppointments = getOutlookAppointments & oAppointmentItem.Subject & vbCrLf & oAppointmentItem.start & oAppointmentItem.End
        
    Next

    MsgBox prompt:=getOutlookAppointments, _
    Title:="Appointments for"
    
    If bOutlookOpened = False Then    'Since we started Outlook, we should close it now that we're done
        oOutlook.Quit 'There seems to be a delay in this action taking place, but does eventually take place
    End If
 
Error_Handler_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oAppointmentItem = Nothing
    Set oFilterAppointments = Nothing
    Set oAppointments = Nothing
    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
    Exit Function

    Resume Error_Handler_Exit
    
    outlookDates = False
End Function
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to skip the instances of recurring appointments? Or master appointments that have recurrences?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko i want to hide master appointments that have recurrences. I don't mind showing the recurring appointment if it falls under my filtered date range

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is a missing `On Error GoTo 0` to turn off the error bypass `On Error Resume Next`.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration
' If desperate declare as Variant


Public Function getOutlookAppointments() As String

    Dim oOutlook              As Object
    Dim oNS                   As Object
    Dim oAppointments         As Object
    Dim oFilterAppointments   As Object
    Dim oAppointmentItem      As Object
    Dim bOutlookOpened        As Boolean
    Dim sfilter               As String
    Dim displayText As String
    Dim startDate As Date
    Const olFolderCalendar = 9
    
    Dim counter As Long
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oOutlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")    'Bind to existing instance of Outlook
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then    'Could not get instance of Outlook, so create a new one
        Err.Clear
        Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        bOutlookOpened = False    'Outlook was not already running, we had to start it
    Else
        bOutlookOpened = True    'Outlook was already running
    End If
    
    ' Consider this mandatory as soon as possible after On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    DoEvents

    Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    'Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    ' Error sorting the folder rather than items
    '  was previously bypassed due to missing On Error GoTo 0
    'oAppointments.Sort "[Start]"
    
    Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).Items    ' <---
    oAppointments.Sort "[Start]"
    
    oAppointments.IncludeRecurrences = True
    
    'startDate = "07/16/2019"
    startDate = Date
    
    'sfilter = ("[Start] < """ & Format(startDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """ and [Start] > """ & Format(startDate + 1, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """")
    sfilter = ("[Start] > """ & Format(startDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """ and [Start] < """ & Format(startDate + 1, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """")
    Debug.Print sfilter
    
    'Set oFilterAppointments = oAppointments.items.Restrict(sfilter)
    Set oFilterAppointments = oAppointments.Restrict(sfilter)
    ' Not useful when .IncludeRecurrences = True
    Debug.Print oFilterAppointments.Count & " appointments found."
    
    'Iterate through each appt in our calendar
    For Each oAppointmentItem In oFilterAppointments
        counter = counter + 1
        getOutlookAppointments = getOutlookAppointments & oAppointmentItem.Subject & " - " & oAppointmentItem.Start & oAppointmentItem.End & vbCrLf
    Next

    Debug.Print counter
    
    MsgBox prompt:=getOutlookAppointments, _
      Title:="Appointments for"
        
    If bOutlookOpened = False Then    'Since we started Outlook, we should close it now that we're done
        oOutlook.Quit 'There seems to be a delay in this action taking place, but does eventually take place
    End If

ExitRoutine:
    Set oAppointmentItem = Nothing
    Set oFilterAppointments = Nothing
    Set oAppointments = Nothing
    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oOutlook = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand the occurrences, you will need to set the `Items.IncludeRecurrences` property - see the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences

Comment: I have already set the `Items.IncludeRecurrences` property to false and still getting recurring events

Comment: Please show your code. Make sure you are not using multiple dot notation when accessing the Items collection.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on a sorted list of occurrences will cause the `IncludeRecurrences` property not to work as expected. For example, the following sequence will return all appointment occurrences; recurring and non-recurring: (1) Sort by Start property (2) Set property to False (3) call Restrict (i.e., filter). See [Items.IncludeRecurrences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.includerecurrences) for more information.

```
    Set oNS = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    startDate = "07/16/2019"

    sfilter = ("[Start] < """ & Format(startDate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """ and [Start] > """ & Format(startDate + 1, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & """")
    Set oFilterAppointments = oAppointments.Items.Restrict(sfilter)
    Debug.Print oFilterAppointments.Count & " appointments found."
```

Comment: I have removed the `.Sort` and set `Include.Recurrences = False` still getting recurring appointments

Comment: Do you mean you get instances of the recurring activities (including the first one)?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev yes, I still continue to get instances of recurring activities